# Getting error "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 406", when calling servlet method

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I am working on client-server application. I am getting error: "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 406" when requesting method from servlet, to get object with selected name. On my server side I got following code in my DataController:

```
 @Controller
    public class DataController {

         @RequestMapping(value = "/getHarnessType")
         @ResponseBody
         public HarnessType getHarnessType(
               @RequestParam("harnessTypeName") String harnessTypeName) {
             GeneratorService generatorService=new GeneratorServiceImpl();
             HarnessType harnessType=generatorService.getHarnessType(harnessTypeName);
             return harnessType;
        }
    }
```

part of source code of my client where I am calling method getHarnessType:

```
String harnessTypeName=jTextField.getText();
url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/getHarnessType?harnessTypeName="+harnessTypeName);
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
OutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                
IOUtils.copy(urlConn.getInputStream(), baos);
```

after proceeding last line I am getting already mentioned error... interesting is, that when i change return type of method getHarnessType to String like:

```
...
public String getHarnessType(
...
return harnessType.getName();
```

and pass only String value to client (not whole object), everything works fine

full stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 406 for URL: http: //localhost:8080/getHarnessType?harnessTypeName=7
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
at formular.Formular2.actionPerformed(Formular2.java:100)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: http://localhost:8080getHarnessType?harnessTypeName= this looks like a / is missing after the port number

Comment: "/" actually is there, dont know why it wasnt copied, I already edited it in the original post

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC or just plain servlets? If so, use the right tags.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the returned object `HarnessType` cannot be parsed correctly. I am not sure if you are using the right configuration of annotation driver.

You can modify your code as following first to see if it works:

```
@Controller
public class DataController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/getHarnessType", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public @ResponseBody HarnessType getHarnessType(
           @RequestParam("harnessTypeName") String harnessTypeName) {
         GeneratorService generatorService=new GeneratorServiceImpl();
         HarnessType harnessType=generatorService.getHarnessType(harnessTypeName);
         return harnessType;
    }
}
```

Comment: i edited my code as you wrote, but error is still the same, I am using "org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;"

Comment: How you access this url by client side? Did you specify the "contentType" to "application/json; charset=UTF-8"? For example, if you are using jquery, it the ajax api should looks like :jQuery.ajax({"type" : "POST","url" : url, "contentType" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8", "dataType" : "json", "data" : yourData,"success" : yourSuccessCallback});

Comment: I just did it by: urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8"); but error still remains

Comment: i tried to add  urlConn.getErrorStream() and i get this message: ...The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers....

Comment: Yes, it is. I mean the way you access the url from client side. You definitely have a js method to fetch the result from client, right? the thing is how you fetch the url from client side? The error message is clear, ""accept" headers". If you are using JQuery as the tool to fetch the url like i said above, the "content-type" and some other parameters will be set into the request headers. Then it make sense, maybe you can try.

Comment: well I'm new to this kind of apps, i dont know  which tool I am using to fetch urls...I m using spring mvc, can you plz explain how can I accept headers?

Comment: Are you response for client development? If so, you need a javascript method to connect with server, right? like: someMethod('/getHarnessType', successCallback, failureCallback). Do u have something like this to communicate with server? By using a method like this, you would get the result that returned by server!

Comment: in my client i just send url(which contains method and parameter) to server, for example: http://localhost:8080/getHarnessType?harnessTypeName=test and server should return object harnessType with name attribute "test"

Comment: Perfect, and what this method looks like? Can you show me the implementation of this method?

Comment: Yes this method is posted in my answer at the top of the page in class DataController

Comment: as I alreadz said, interesting thing is, that when i tested it and changed type return value of that method to normal String for example return "test"; all the process worked well

Comment: Yes, it is because the String "test" doesn't need a parsing process. It's just a string. But if you returned an Object, it requires a parsing process to parse it into JSON format.

Comment: You mean your client is not a html based app, but a Swing or swt based one?

Comment: I tried the code that you provided, it works fine. So it should be something wrong in your springMVC configuration.

Comment: and did you tried it on your own created object? can you post a sourcecode here?or send me sourcecodes on misoorulez@gmail.com?so i can check where I am making mistake. thx

Comment: I can make an example for you. I will send it to your mailbox later on.

Comment: hi nanfeng, I tried your app but i m getting still the same error, i guess i got some missing dependencies, (i cant use maven due to my company internet restrictions) would you be so kind and write me which jar file do I need?

Comment: I've sent it to your mailbox. The jackson version is most likely your problem.

Comment: hi, i just figured out that it was probably problem with spring spring security, which intercepts /getData request, but now, i ve got new error...java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/getHarnessType
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
 at tutorial.Test.main

Comment: tomcat error: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.isEnabled(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig$Feature;)Z] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.isEnabled(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig$Feature;)Z
 at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal

Comment: This might be the jackson version issue that i mentioned in email. It seems you imported a non-matched jackson with spring. It's better you google the spring version first to see what version of jackson should be used for it. Take my example for instance, my spring is 3.2.0.RELEASE, only jackson 1.8.7 can be used pair with it.

Comment: hi, I just get my app worked somehow, by using example project that you sent me. Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with the client, try adding accept headers, I guess you are not using browser. If the Web server detects that the data it wants to return is not acceptable to the client, it returns a header containing the 406 error code.
If the problem is still not solved, please add the stack trace.

Comment: I m pretty new to these kind of applications, can you plz explain how to add accept headers? thx

Comment: i tried to add urlConn.getErrorStream() and i get this message: ...The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers....

Comment: Try using ObjectOutputStream object instead of ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

try setting `urlConn .setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");`
Error 406 means something wrong in your client side request. It is not capable of accepting the response. See [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: i tried to add urlConn.getErrorStream() and i get this message: ...The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers....